# Error: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, server

i'm builduing a chat app with python that makes it's user could communicate with other devices which are connected to the same network in CMD

obviously it s my first time using the socket library and the whole concept is new to me

the problem is whenever i run the code in a local device it runs properly but when i try to run it in another devices it doesn t . i have tried to change the ip adress in the client code but it don t work properly and shows me this error

```
Error: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

any help ?

this is the first code of the server:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PORT = 5002 
separator_token = "<SEP>" 

client_sockets = set()
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

def listen_for_client(cs):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = cs.recv(1024).decode()
        except Exception as e:
            
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")
            client_sockets.remove(cs)
        else:
           
            msg = msg.replace(separator_token, ": ")
        for client_socket in client_sockets:
            client_socket.send(msg.encode())

while True:
   
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] {client_address} connected."
    client_sockets.add(client_socket)
    t = Thread(target=listen_for_client, args=(client_socket,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for cs in client_sockets:
    cs.close()
s.close()
```

and here the client code

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime

SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1" #i know this must be changed to devices ip adress
SERVER_PORT = 5002 
separator_token = "<SEP>" 
s = socket.socket()
print(f"[*] Connecting to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
print("[+] Connected.")
name = input("Enter your name: ")
def listen_for_messages():
    while True:
        message = s.recv(1024).decode()
        print("\n" + message)
t = Thread(target=listen_for_messages)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Comment: Maybe a firewall is interfering.